# JQuery complicated class and ID sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Unfortunately, I could not solve that myself. I have a list with several DIV which ALWAYS have the same ID and class. The list I sort according to the "data-sort" attributes and it works wonderfully.

Currently it looks like this:

```
<div id="divList">

<div id="hsdf" data-sort="1"></div>
<div class="hsdf" data-sort="1"></div>

<div class="vasfd" data-sort="2"></div>
<div id="vasfd" data-sort="2"></div>

<div id="asdfas" data-sort="3"></div>
<div class="asdfas" data-sort="3"></div>

</div>
```

I would like however in the list sorting first the class and then the ID comes. Like here:

```
<div id="divList">

<div class="hsdf" data-sort="1"></div>
<div id="hsdf" data-sort="1"></div>

<div class="vasfd" data-sort="2"></div>
<div id="vasfd" data-sort="2"></div>

<div class="asdfas" data-sort="3"></div>
<div id="asdfas" data-sort="3"></div>

</div>
```

The "data-sort" attribute sorting is done with the jQuery:

```
jQuery('#divList').find('div').sort(function (a, b) {
return jQuery(a).attr('data-sort') - jQuery(b).attr('data-sort');
}).appendTo('#divList');
```

Do you have any ideas for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your `sort` function:

```
return jQuery(a).attr('data-sort') - jQuery(b).attr('data-sort')
  || !!jQuery(a).attr("id") - !!jQuery(a).attr("class");
```

This checks for the existence of an `id` and for a `class`. If the class exists, the expression after `||` will evalutate to `-1`, if the ID exists, it will evalutate to `1`. This will be relevant if the expression *before* `||` evaluates to `0` (when they have the same `data-sort` value).

Comment: Thanks, so it worked. "B" instead of "A" 

`                    return jQuery(a).attr('data-sort') - jQuery(b).attr('data-sort')
                        || !jQuery(b).attr('id') - !jQuery(b).attr('class');`

Comment: @od_ Those are equivalent. The sorting function compares `a` and `b`. My approach sorts `a` first, if it has a class, your approach sorts `b` last, if it has an ID. In this scenario, it’s the same.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
jQuery('#divList').find('div').sort(function (a, b) {
    var diff = jQuery(a).attr('data-sort') - jQuery(b).attr('data-sort');
    if (diff == 0) {
        if (jQuery(a).attr('class') && jQuery(a).attr('class') != '') {
            diff = -1;
        } else {
            diff = 1;
        }
    }
    return diff;
}).appendTo('#divList');
```